# Binary Search for square root from leetcode oj

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

```
public static int sqrt(int x) {

     if( x == 0 || x == 1){
         return x;
     }
     long start = 0;
     long end = x;


     while ( end-start > 1){
         long mid = (int)(end + start) / 2;
         long s = mid * mid;

         if(s == x){
             return (int)mid;
         }
         else if(s > x){
             end = mid;
         }
         else {
             start = mid;
         }

     }

     return (int)start;
    }
```

Above is the working code snippet. I have questions as below. Thank you in advance for helping. ;-)

1. While(end-start > 1) why we need 1 here? just because the return signiture is int?
2. If we change while loop from while(end-start > 1) to while(end > start), we have to make end = mid-1; and start = mid + 1, correct? Still one step move, i wonder if this is also due to return type is integer?
3. Why we cannot return ***end?*** or (***int)(start+end)/2***?? I saw almost 99% answer return to the left bound of binary search. I just want to know if return to right boundry or the middle one is fine?

Answer (score 0):

The return type `int` simply means you are return a result which is of type `int`. It has nothing to do with the algorithm inside the method body. Below I have tried to answer your questions:

1. `While(end-start > 1)` is used to make sure `end` is always greater than `start`. if `end-start` is 1 or less than 1, that means you have reached end of binary search.
2. You can go ahead and change `while(end-start > 1)` to `while(end > start)`, it will still work. Don't have to make `end = mid-1` and start = `mid+1`.
3. It all depends where you answer lies. It can be different for each problem.

You should try the link below to understand binary search algorithm better.

http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binarySearch

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Meena. I will do more research into your suggested link. One more thing I'm curious is why not using while(end-start>0.1) the epsilon can be changed to any number, right? Also, I don't think we can leave end=mid or start=mid - it will cause dead loop - no way to jump out of the while loop

Comment: @doglas No, it won't cause a infinite loop if that is what you mean coz `else if(s > x){end = mid;}else {start = mid;}` will update `start` and `end` on every loop.

Comment: Nope. if you try the following code, it won't work. `while ( end > start){
            long mid = (int)(end + start) / 2;
            long s = mid * mid;
            
            if(s == x){
                return (int)mid;
            }
            else if(s > x){
                end = mid;
            }
            else {
                start = mid;
            }
        
        }`